# Ruby timezone offset problem

Tags: ruby, timezone

I need to assign a timezone offset to a Time to get current day of the week for a specified offset.
This is not with rails so I need a pure Ruby formatter/parser to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I found:

```
require 'date'
local = DateTime.now 
new_offset = Rational(0, 24) #put the offset you want as first argument
utc = local.new_offset(new_offset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns the offset in seconds between the timezone of time and UTC.

```
   t = Time.gm(2000,1,1,20,15,1)   #=> 2000-01-01 20:15:01 UTC
   t.gmt_offset                    #=> 0
   l = t.getlocal                  #=> 2000-01-01 14:15:01 -0600
   l.gmt_offset                    #=> -21600
```

Comment: But how do I convert this time to for example offset +7? My question is I want to get day of the week at specific offset (explicitly specified) not UTC or machine local time. So when creating a date/time obj how do I assign a timezone offset?

Answer (score 0):

```
#As a string
t = Time.new(2011,6,27,14,10,0, "+07:00")
# or in seconds from UTC
t = Time.new(2011,6,27,14,10,0, 7*60*60)
```